# Spring "Hello, World" project configuration problems

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

I'm building a simple web app from a Spring Web Maven Project, and I'm having trouble getting my annotations work properly. This project has a Dynamic Web Facet, and is being deployed to a Tomcat 7 server.

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<display-name>abbas-tables</display-name>

<!--
    - Location of the XML file that defines the root application context.
    - Applied by ContextLoaderListener.
-->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring/application-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<!--
    - Servlet that dispatches request to registered handlers (Controller implementations).
-->

<servlet>
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

And my mvc-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


     <context:component-scan
        base-package="org.springframework.samples.web"/>


<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <!-- Example: a logical view name of 'showMessage' is mapped to '/WEB-INF/jsp/showMessage.jsp' -->
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

And my application-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


     <context:component-scan
        base-package="org.springframework.samples.service"/>
```

And my controller class - with a simple system out (which isn't firing):

```
package com.abbas.core.main;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest ;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse ;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller ;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping ;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView ;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController ;

@Controller
public class AbbasTablesController extends AbstractController{
@RequestMapping(value="/departments")
public String simplePattern(){

  System.out.println("simplePattern method was called");
  return "someResult";

}

@Override
protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal( HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1 )
    throws Exception {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null ;
  }
 }
```

But I go to localhost:8080/abbas-tables/departments AND localhost:8080/departments, and I get the Tomcat "cannot find resource" screen.
I'm including my directory structure, too, in case it's the issue.

[image]

Here's the error:

[image]

Comment: Where is your file called someresult.jsp. Spring is trying to look for that.

Comment: I'm still trying to get the mapping to fire; that System.out isn't showing yet.

Comment: It wont. Just change the return type matching your jsp name.

Answer (score 0):

component-scan base-package="org.springframework.samples.web"

seems to be incorrect.

As the package for controller is different, u might b getting this error.

Change it to:
component-scan base-package="ocom.abbas.core.main"

Answer (score 0):

Change the below from :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/departments")
public String simplePattern(){

  System.out.println("simplePattern method was called");
  return "someResult";
}
```

TO :

```
   @RequestMapping(value="/departments")
    public String simplePattern(){

      System.out.println("simplePattern method was called");
      return "showMessage";
    }
```

As I cannot see any JSP with name showResult. And you are not even adding any model attributes or anything.

Comment: Also, prakash it correct, your basepackage name is wrong.

Comment: I did both those things, and it's still throwing the error.

Comment: What is the errror?Can you edit your main post to include the error. I will be going in 10 minutes, so before that please.

Comment: Yarp - give me a sec.